# Can anyone explain how does the following recursion work?

Tags: java, recursion

I have some trouble understanding the following recursive code:

```
public class recursive {
    public static void main(String[] args){ 
        helper(0) ;
    }

    public static void helper(int i){
        int a=3;
        if(i==a){
            System.out.println("yes:"+i);
            return;
        }else{
            for(;i<a;i++){ 
                System.out.println("no:"+i);
                helper(i+1);
                System.out.println("end:"+i);
            }
        }
    }         
}
```

The Output is as follows:

```
no:0
no:1
no:2
yes:3
end:2 //why this is 2?
end:1 //why this is 1?
no:2
yes:3
end:2
end:0
no:1
no:2
yes:3
end:2
end:1
no:2
yes:3
end:2
```

I do not understand why the first end is 2. Can anyone explain how does the recursion work in this simple program?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
public static void helper(int i){
    int a=3;
    if(i==a){
        System.out.println("yes:"+i);
        return;
    }else{
        System.out.println("no:"+i);
        helper(i+1);
    }
}
```

one idea of recursion is to do away with loops

Comment: i understand if there is no loop. But I feel confused when the code is like the one I have offered.

Comment: because `helper` does not return to print `end` until it has printed `yes`.  Try using a pencil and paper to follow the flow.

Comment: the thing that I do not understand is why it return to the loop where i==2, then directly return to loop where i==1 without continue anything in loop i==2?

Answer (score 1):

Each call to `helper` has its own local value of `i`.

So when `i==2`, and you call `helper(i+1)`, the next call to `helper` has `i==3`, but when it returns, it goes back to the previous `helper` invocation, for which `i==2`.

Comment: thx for your answer. So it go back to previous helper, for which i==2. Then, why it return to i=1? as a print out of end:1? why doesn't it stay in end:2 until i==3?

Comment: @b1694621 After it goes back to the previous helper, it goes to the helper before it, for which `i==1`.